# How do you combine DTO's properly in DropWizard?

Tags: java, dropwizard

In my Dropwizard project I have defined DTO's that Jackson maps to JSON, e.g.

```
public class UserDTO implements Principal {
    private String username;
    private int role;
    private String realName;
    private String apartment;

    public UserDTO(String username, int role, String realName, String apartment) {
        this.username = username;
        this.role = role;
        this.realName = realName;
        this.apartment = apartment;
    }

    public String getRealName() {
        return realName;
    }

    public String getApartment() {
        return apartment;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return username;
    }

    public int getRole() {
        return role;
    }
}
```

This is all fine and dandy. Now I may have another DTO for exporting some statistics about a given user:

```
public class UsageDTO {
    private int sumOfWashingMachineUses;
    private int sumOfTumbleDryUses;
    private int month;
    private int year;

    public UsageDTO(int sumOfWashingMachineUses, int sumOfTumbleDryUses, int year, int month) {
        this.sumOfWashingMachineUses = sumOfWashingMachineUses;
        this.sumOfTumbleDryUses = sumOfTumbleDryUses;
        this.year = year;
        this.month = month;
    }

    public int getSumOfWashingMachineUses() {
        return sumOfWashingMachineUses;
    }

    public int getSumOfTumbleDryUses() {
        return sumOfTumbleDryUses;
    }

    public int getMonth() {
        return month;
    }

    public int getYear() {
        return year;
    }
}
```

Everything is great. But at some point I may want to combine details from either one of these classes. What is the best way to do this? So far I have been creating a new class for every type of content the server is able to return. It seems like I'm repeating a lot of stuff in these (dumb) classes. Is this really the way to go?

Comment: put the common stuff in parent class and extend it to those classes that share the common attributes. or add those common stuff in one class and add object of that class in each of your classes (composition)

Comment: This seems more suited to codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Sorry did not know of that stackexchange, will post there instead.